# Power Automate - send email with submitted form

Tags: form, power-automate

I have a microsoft form survey. When the form is completed power automate sends thank you email. The business wants to include the completed form in the email. Is it possible send the completed form without inputting 20 different fields in the email body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont believe there is. But even with twenty questions it will take a matter of minutes to set it up. And you can make it look pretty/highlight negative surveys or what ever will rock their boat. Business will be happy :)

By the way, I would recommend to make the email body in a "Compose" action and put the output of that compose action into the body of the email since working with text formats/logic in the email body can be quite frustrating.

Go make the business happy! :)